# Adding a tag in the upper right hand corner of a widget

Tags: java, android, widget

How could I add a small tag containing a text in the upper right hand corner of my widget? I'm looking for something like the tag which can be seen on mail apps widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a FrameLayout with your widget on the background and a TextView (your tag) with a gravity setting of top|right.